# C++ delete syntax

Tags: c++

I came across this rather unusual usage of 'delete'. Just wanted to know if the following line deletes both pointers or only the first?

```
delete ptr1, ptr2
```

Comment: Just as an aside, the delete keyword is only relevant to C++ and has nothing to do with C.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is undoubtedly an error.  The comma here is the comma operator, not a separator.  Only the first pointer, `ptr1` is deleted.

The second pointer, `ptr2`, is just a do-nothing expression.

The `delete` operator has higher precedence than the `,` operator, so the expression is parsed as if it were written:

```
(delete ptr1) , (ptr2)
```

and not as if it were written:

```
delete (ptr1 , ptr2)
```

If `,` had higher precedence than `delete`, then only the *second* pointer would be deleted.

Comment: I though the result of a comma operator was the last expression in the comma separated list (thus like your original answer should it not be ptr2 that is deleted) or is there something more tricky going on here?

Comment: @Martin:  +1 to your answer, because it's quite convoluted (both of the first two answers were initially incorrect; it wasn't until I had written an example and tested it that I realized the precedence issue).  I updated with an explanation of why the first pointer is deleted.

Comment: I saw that after I posted, good catch. I would have never seen that nice twist without a compiler and a test case

Comment: Shouldn't the conclusion be that there's no way to delete multiple pointers in 1 line? Grouping pointers by parenthesis changes the precedence, but doesn't call delete multiple times.

Answer (score 12):

James McNellis is correct that this is comma operator, but he has the operator precedence wrong. He's (apparently) thinking it works out as:

```
delete (ptr1, ptr2);
```

in which case he'd be right -- it would only delete the second item. In reality, however, delete is also an operator, and has substantially higher precedence than the comma operator (which has about as low of precedence as possible), so it really works out as:

```
(delete ptr1), ptr2;
```

So it deletes the first pointer, and the result of the expression is the value of the second pointer -- which hasn't been deleted, so it's still valid (if it was previously).

I'd echo Martin York's conclusion, and I think this backs it up. I doubt that even one whole percent of C++ programmers know C++ as well as James McNellis -- when his answer about what a construct does is wrong, it's a solid indication that almost nobody will know what it really does. I'd posit that nobody at all can be sure it's doing what was intended. In fact, I'd guess it was intended to delete both objects, which it *should* not do (i.e., won't unless the compiler has a bug).

[Edit: I see that while I was writing this, James has corrected his answer. My apologies to James -- but I think the basic conclusion stands, so I'm not deleting this, at least for now.]

Comment: No apologies necessary; my original answer was quite wrong and in hindsight, I should have used strikethrough when editing so it was clear it had been edited in the five minute window.

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't recommend it, but the following will work -

```
delete ( delete p1, p2 );
```

This can be generalized as follows -

```
delete ( delete ( delete p1, p2 ), p3 );
delete ( delete ( delete ( delete p1, p2 ), p3 ), p4 );
```

Comment: That may be correct but it is totally unhelpful to the extreme.

Comment: "I wouldn't recommend it, but a shotgun will remove a splinter from your toe by doing the following..." Just don't give bad advice in the first place.

Comment: Actually, it is useful to know how operators work. It may not be *advisable* in this situation, but it's still good to know.

Answer (score 5):

Just looking at it scares me.

Don't use this even if it is legal as most people have to stop and think ( and will still get it wrong (one of the first two answers has to be wrong as they contradict each other, my first instinct is comma operator problems (but I don't know))).

Even now I would not answer the question until I had written an example and tested it and even then I would be scared of corner cases in the language that would cause problems.

Comment: Writing Lisp daily? Btw, you forgot a ) :P

Comment: Fixed   (now more than 15 char)           :-)

Answer (score 5):

Consider this sample code:

```
class foo
{
    int _a;
public:
    foo(int a) : _a(a) { }
    ~foo() { printf("~foo() %d\n", _a); }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    foo *p1 = new foo(1), *p2 = new foo(2);
    delete p1, p2;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
~foo() 1
```

The reason, as already answered by James, is operator precedence.