# c++ Make pointer point to another inside a function

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working on something which lead me to a situation similar to the example below. I want **b** to point to **a** after on *test()*. Is it possible to this or creating a copy is the only solution?

Thanks.

```
void test(Object* a, Object* b)
{
    std::cout << "test a: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "test b: " << b << std::endl;
    b = a;
    std::cout << "test b assigned: " << b << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Object* a = new Object();
    Object* b = nullptr;
    test(a, b);
    std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b: " << b << std::endl;
    delete a;
    delete b;
}

test a: 0x1aa8930
test b: 0
test b assigned: 0x1aa8930
a: 0x1aa8930
b: 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't, because you pass the value of b, not a reference (or a pointer) to it, which is required to be able to modify it. Variables can only be modified by a function if that function receives the address of those variables, and that can only happen via either a pointer (so you'd have Object**) or a reference (Object* &)

Comment: In addition to Paul: with `void test(Object *a, Object *&b)` it would work.

Comment: No such thing as `void main()`

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037655/c-delete-syntax

Comment: You want a double pointer (pointer to pointer - `**b`) or reference to pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
void test(Object* a, Object*& b)
{
    std::cout << "test a: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "test b: " << b << std::endl;
    b = a;
    std::cout << "test b assigned: " << b << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Object* a = new Object();
    Object* b = NULL;
    test(a, b);
    std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b: " << b << std::endl;
    delete a, b;
}
```

Output will be:

```
test a: 0x7a0d28
test b: 0
test b assigned: 0x7a0d28
a: 0x7a0d28
b: 0x7a0d28
```

Its because in question, you have passed the value of b, not a reference to it, which is required to modify it. Variables can only be modified by a function if that function receives the address of those variables, and that can only can be done via either a pointer (Object**) or a reference (Object* &)

Comment: You should explain *why* what you posted works. Don't just drop code and say "do this" without an explanation. That's not helpful in order to understand what was wrong. See for example the answer by @StereoBucket

Comment: @JesperJuhl Done

Answer (score 4):

In order to modify a pointer, you need to either:

- Pass a pointer to your pointer
  `void test(Object **a, Object **b)`
  `test(&a,&b);`
  After which you need to dereference that if you want to change the pointer.
- Pass a reference to your pointer
  `void test(Object *&a, Object *&b)`
  `test(a,b);`
  Here you won't have to dereference anything if you want to change the address.

For `a`, you don't necessarily have to pass a pointer to pointer or a reference to pointer (unless you plan to modify it too in the future), but for `b` you have to in order to modify it.

P.S. change your `void main()` to `int main()`

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays we have something called `shared_ptr`, which does exacly what you want. Plus you don't have to clean it up after you're finished with it!

Example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using Object = int;

void test(const std::shared_ptr<Object>& a, std::shared_ptr<Object>& b)
{
    b = a;
    std::cout << "test b assigned: " << b.get() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_shared<Object>();
    std::shared_ptr<Object> b;

    std::cout << "test a: " << a.get() << "\n";
    std::cout << "test b: " << b.get() << "\n";

    test(a, b);

    std::cout << "test a: " << a.get() << "\n";
    std::cout << "test b: " << b.get() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

output (g++  5.4.0):

```
test a: 0x21e2c30
test b: 0
test b assigned: 0x21e2c30
test a: 0x21e2c30
test b: 0x21e2c30
```

[live demo](http://rextester.com/IAE60812)